# C++ linking issue with -fPIC? Segment fault

Tags: c++, linker, runtime-error, linker-errors

I am compiling my code using g++

```
g++ -g  -O3 -fPIC -shared -lstdc++ -std=c++0x  -I/home/nikesh.joshi/somepath/ main.cpp   /home/nikesh.joshi/ml/somepath_apis/somepath/somefile.o
```

I have already included lib using ldconfig command.
I need to use -fPIC because eventually this library will be linked with other static libraries to form a dynamic library.
When I run this code using the following command

```
./a.out
```

It gives "Segment Fault".

code of main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
        cout<<"Hello";
}
```

If I compile this code using g++ main.cpp then code run successfully. I need to compile this code with all lib, so I can use functions of these libs.

I found same problem here : [Why does including -fPIC to compile a static library cause a segmentation fault at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842036/why-does-including-fpic-to-compile-a-static-library-cause-a-segmentation-fault)

But this does not resolve my problem.

Comment: "_But this does not resolve my problem._" Please elaborate on _how_ / _why_ it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I am still having segment fault issue, I dont know reason, do I need to give lib path while running a.out also? The link I mentioned does not have the solution to the problem. See in answer comment of link.

Comment: So where does this segmentation fault occur? What is the call stack?

Comment: No stack call. Just one line output "segment fault".

Comment: Can't figureout what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-shared` produces a shared object that can be linked with other objects. It does not create an executable. You cannot just execute a shared object. Either link with something else to produce an executable, or don't create a dynamic library in the first place.

Comment: If you actually need an [executable .so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449987/building-a-so-that-is-also-an-executable), you need to replace (or override) `-shared` with `-pie`.